# Add person types programmatically on bookable product creation in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-bookings

Basically I'm trying to add a new bookable product in Woocommerce using a custom form I've made, so I have to add the products programmatically. Creating the product is fine, the problem is that I can't figure out how to add a new person type to my product so I can fix multiple prices.

Does someone have an idea how to do this?

This is the code I have so far.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title' => $_POST["title"],
    'post_content' => $_POST["description"],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'booking', 'product_type' );
```

Comment: what exactly you mean by person type i din't understand your question  correctly can you please explain more?

Comment: @kashalo In woocommerce bookings you can set different person types for each booking product…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  thanks for explanation I will install the booking plugin and look around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will enable "has persons" and create your person types for a bookable product:

```
// Create the product
$product_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_title' => $_POST["title"],
    'post_content' => $_POST["description"],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => "product",
) );

// Set the product type
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'booking', 'product_type' );

// Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Enable persons and save
$product->set_has_persons(true);
$product->save();

// Here define your person types (one array by person type)
$persons_type_data =  array(
    // First person type
    array( 
        'block_cost'  => 0,
        'cost'        => 16.50,
        'description' => '',
        'max'         => '',
        'min'         => '',
        'name'        => __('Adults'),
    ),
    // Second person type
    array(
        'block_cost'  => 0,
        'cost'        => 9.20,
        'description' => '',
        'max'         => '',
        'min'         => '',
        'name'        => __('Childs'),
    ),
);

// Loop Through persons type data
foreach( $persons_type_data as $key => $values ){
    $person_type = new WC_Product_Booking_Person_Type();
    $person_type->set_block_cost($values['block_cost']);
    $person_type->set_cost($values['cost']);
    $person_type->set_description($values['description']);
    $person_type->set_max($values['max']);
    $person_type->set_min($values['min']);
    $person_type->set_name($values['name']);
    $person_type->set_parent_id($product_id);
    $person_type->set_sort_order($key); // Sorting is based on the array order

    // Save the person type
    $person_type->save();

    // Add the person type to the array
    $persons[] = $person_type;
}
// Set person types and save the product
$product->set_person_types($persons);
$product->save();
```

Tested and works.